# GIT clone issue in Jenkins Permission Denied

Tags: git, shell, jenkins

I am trying to pull some documents from git using `git clone` as part of a jenkins process. Git clone works fine separately, but as a part of jenkins, I am facing permission denied issue

```
> echo "pw"| sudo git clone host@IP:git-repo 


> Cloning into 'git-repo'... 
Permission denied, please try again.
Permission denied, please try again.
Permission denied(publickey,password).
```

fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Comment: Does the `echo "pw" |` part as a whole work fine separately?

Answer (score 1):

Try using the SSH Agent plugin to make your private key accessible to regular build steps.

Answer (score 1):

Jenkins creates a system user to your system with name jenkins.

1. SSH to your server.
2. Switch user to jenkins.
3. Try git clone.

Try adding jenkins user to sudores using this [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/7477/how-can-i-add-a-new-user-as-sudoer-using-the-command-line) and give permissions to this user, add [SSH(git)](https://github.com/settings/ssh) key for git clone.

This may solve your issue. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
superuser ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL - for single user
```

refer [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/334318/sudoers-file-enable-nopasswd-for-user-all-commands)

This setting help us to bypass user prompt.